# Export import oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, import

I met the following presented problem, during the Import operation to our Datawarehouse database. What could be the reason for these raised errors with codes `ORA-39002` and `ORA-39166` :

```
C:\Users\kmaaz>expdp bank/b123 tables=employee,transaction,branch,account directory=my_dir dumpfile=tables_dump.dmp logfile=tables_log.log

Export: Release 12.1.0.2.0 - Production on Mon May 28 07:21:51 2018

Copyright (c) 1982, 2014, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

Connected to: Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Advanced Analytics and Real Application Testing options
Starting "BANK"."SYS_EXPORT_TABLE_01":  bank/******** tables=employee,transaction,branch,account directory=my_dir dumpfile=tables_dump.dmp logfile=tables_log.log
Estimate in progress using BLOCKS method...
Processing object type TABLE_EXPORT/TABLE/TABLE_DATA
Total estimation using BLOCKS method: 192 KB
Processing object type TABLE_EXPORT/TABLE/TABLE
Processing object type TABLE_EXPORT/TABLE/GRANT/OWNER_GRANT/OBJECT_GRANT
Processing object type TABLE_EXPORT/TABLE/CONSTRAINT/CONSTRAINT
Processing object type TABLE_EXPORT/TABLE/INDEX/STATISTICS/INDEX_STATISTICS
Processing object type TABLE_EXPORT/TABLE/STATISTICS/TABLE_STATISTICS
Processing object type TABLE_EXPORT/TABLE/STATISTICS/MARKER
. . exported "BANK"."ACCOUNT"                            10.21 KB       1 rows
. . exported "BANK"."BRANCH"                             6.789 KB       1 rows
. . exported "BANK"."EMPLOYEE"                           7.632 KB       1 rows
. . exported "BANK"."TRANSACTION"                            0 KB       0 rows
Master table "BANK"."SYS_EXPORT_TABLE_01" successfully loaded/unloaded
******************************************************************************
Dump file set for BANK.SYS_EXPORT_TABLE_01 is:
  D:\EXPORT\TABLES_DUMP.DMP
Job "BANK"."SYS_EXPORT_TABLE_01" successfully completed at Mon May 28 07:21:59 2018 elapsed 0 00:00:07


C:\Users\kmaaz>impdp dwh/d123 tables=employee,transaction,branch,account directory=my_dir dumpfile=tables_dump.dmp logfile=tables_log.log

Import: Release 12.1.0.2.0 - Production on Mon May 28 07:22:08 2018

Copyright (c) 1982, 2014, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

Connected to: Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Advanced Analytics and Real Application Testing options
ORA-39002: invalid operation
ORA-39166: Object DWH.ACCOUNT was not found or could not be exported or imported.
ORA-39166: Object DWH.BRANCH was not found or could not be exported or imported.
ORA-39166: Object DWH.TRANSACTION was not found or could not be exported or imported.
ORA-39166: Object DWH.EMPLOYEE was not found or could not be exported or imported.
```

[Screenshot about importing data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XmyN1.jpg)

Comment: what has this got to do with java?

Comment: It's better not to post your database passwords...

Answer (score 2):

- First of all, Make sure you have `IMP_FULL_DATABASE` privilege
  granted.
- Most probably `ORA-39166` [ objects can not be found ] errors are
  raised due to missing *`REMAP_SCHEMA=BANK:DWH`* *clause* in the *impdp
  statement*. For this reason the locations of the objects can not be
  determined.